# Get compilation warning at correct position (`gcc`)

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings

In [this example powered by Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/jNxO6b), and reproduced below,
it's possible to create a function which requires its parameters to respect some conditions `(i >= 0)`, `ptr != NULL`, etc.

```
// EXPECT() : will trigger a warning if the condition is not guaranteed
#define EXPECT(c)  (void)((c) ? (void)0 : never_reach())

// assume() : tell the compiler that `cond` is true
// note : only works for simple conditions, such as `i>=0`.
// Avoid complex conditions invoking functions.
#define assume(cond) do { if (!(cond)) __builtin_unreachable(); } while (0)


// *********************************************************
// Function declaration
// *********************************************************

int positive_plus1_body(int v); 
#define positive_plus1_preconditions(v)   ((v)>=0)     // Let's first define the preconditions. 
                                                       // Name is long, because conditions must be unique to the function

// The inlined function express the contract, with both pre and post conditions.
// `inline` is essential, so that actual input values get verified,
// and result gets enriched with `assume` conditions.
// Problem is, the error is now located INTO the inlined function, not at the place where it's called.
// This makes it very hard to identify where the problem happens.
static inline int positive_plus1(int v)                // Ideally, this function should also have additional attribute to not trigger warnings when it's not invoked
{
    int r;
    EXPECT(positive_plus1_preconditions(v));           // preconditions
    r = positive_plus1_body(v);
    assume(r > 0);                                     // postconditions
    return r;
}
```

The [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/jNxO6b) live example makes it possible to call the function with good and wrong parameters, and witness the impact on compilation diagnosis.

If the caller doesn't respect the conditions, the compiler generates a warning. This is pretty convenient to immediately detect condition violations. The usual alternative is to use `assert()` inside the function body, but relies on runtime tests to detect potential condition violations, which is less immediate, and less certain.

Problem is, if the `inline` function is called with wrong arguments, the compiler will locate the condition violation *inside* the `inline` function. This diagnosis is of limited usefulness. Instead, we would like to read the line at which the `inline` function is called with incorrect arguments.

The work around is to use a macro instead. However, a macro will trigger the famous multi evaluation problem, since its arguments must be used multiple times. This is dangerous enough to avoid it. Also, the encapsulating `inline` function could be automatically generated with a macro, but a macro cannot be generated by another macro.

Another solution is to use a [statement expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html), which solves the multi-evaluation problem. However, it's non portable, and it's still a macro, so it cannot be generated by another macro.

It would be preferable to keep the `inline` function of the example if possible. But generating the correct line number where the condition violation happens is quite important. 
Is there a way to achieve that while keeping the `inline` function approach ?

Comment: Hi Eugene ! Minimal example reproduced in the question body. Note that the Godbolt link feels way better, since the full example is larger, and can be modified live to impact compilation outcome and witness the result.

Comment: Your question might get answered by one of the wizards which need only too look at the code and tell the solution, without the need to compile or modify anything :) Having that link is a good addition but not a replacement for MCVE. But you probably know that.